# How to disable Profiles in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, profile

I have used Chrome without a profile.  Some months ago, I clicked something or answered some questions resulting in two profiles.  They have a crazy split of bookmarks and profile photo etc.  And every time I start chrome, I have to answer a stupid question about which profile to use.

**Is there a way to merge the bookmarks together and then disable the profile option?**
No, I don't want my bookmarks synced with anything.  I suspect that I gave the answer to a question on syncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to merge the bookmarks from multiple profiles in Google Chrome and disable the profile option. Here's how you can do it:

1. In Chrome, click on the three dots in the top-right corner of the window, then select "Bookmarks" from the menu.
2. In the Bookmarks Manager, click on the "Organize" dropdown menu and select "Import bookmarks."
3. In the Import Bookmarks and Settings window, select the profile that you want to import the bookmarks from, then click "Import."
4. Repeat this process for each of the profiles that you want to merge the bookmarks from.
5. Once you have imported all of the bookmarks from the different profiles, you can disable the profile option by going to Settings > People > Manage other people, and clicking the "Remove" button next to the profile that you no longer want to use.

Keep in mind that this process will only merge the bookmarks from the different profiles, and will not merge other profile-specific data such as history or saved passwords. If you want to merge this information as well, you will need to use a third-party tool to do so.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting the answer, finally got around to trying it.

Answer (score 1):

As Sahil explained, it is possible to merge bookmarks between Chrome profiles. To prevent Chrome from prompting to select a profile, delete any extra profiles using these steps:

1. Close and re-open Chrome.
2. A window is displayed asking you to select a profile.
3. Click on the ellipses on the profile that you wish to delete to display a short menu.[image]
4. Select the option to delete the profile and then confirm the deletion.
   [image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).